# Jquery Если время больше чем 12:00, то вывести getDate + 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, время

```
var now = new Date();
let time = now.getHours().toString(); //так мы получим только часы
let date = now.getDate().toString(); //так текущую дату

if (time >= 12){
    console.log(time);
}
```

Я же хочу чтобы если время было больше 12:00 (важно учитывать минуты), то что-то делаем...
Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

в общем-то надо добавить минуты и их тоже сравнить:

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getHours().toString();
var date_now = parseInt(now.getDate());
var minutes = now.getMinutes().toString();
if (time >= 12 && minutes > 0){
    console.log('OK');
}
```